# iPad iOS 10 - Can I hide songs in the Music app that I have purchased?

Tags: ios, itunes, ipad, icloud

I have a brand new iPad and upgraded to iOS 10.

I have thousands of purchases on iTunes that I don't want cluttering the lists in the Music app.  This was very easy on my iPhone 6 (iOS 8.4).
I don't see an option in Settings > iTunes, Music, or iCloud.

How do I hide them?

- I don't have a computer to do this through iTunes on a PC or Mac.

[image]

Comment: This is not a duplicate as the previous post clarifies how to hide purchased, cloud-stored songs via iTunes on a Mac or PC.  I want to know how to do it from my iPad and iPhone with the new iOS10.

Comment: It did not help as it does not address my question. The link you provided in that thread was also provided below, but does not address my issue.   I am trying to hide music purchases on my iPad directly on the iPad -not using iTunes through a PC or a Mac because I have neither.

Comment: Note that it says "app purchases in the App Store" - not music, movie, etc. purchases from the iTunes Store.  These are not the same thing.  I am not attempting hide app purchases.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can 'hide' them.

From the main screen, tap on Downloaded Music.

You'll then be on a screen which is basically exactly the same as the previous one with options for Albums, Artists, etc, which will only show music on your device.

To make it more accessible, I suggest tapping Edit in the main Library screen and dragging the Downloaded Music row up to the top. Note also that whatever you make visible or hidden on this Edit screen will also take effect on the Downloaded Music screen (eg making Compilations visible, Artists invisible, etc).

Note, there is no option to get rid of the initial Library screen. IE we want to effectively make the Downloaded Music screen the top level - there is no way to do that.

Comment: And hooray that the new music app now shows the duration of albums again!

Comment: But I can't believe they got rid of the ability to do star ratings. :(

Comment: This works and is basically the same as the "show only downloaded" feature in the past version.  The downside being that was a one time setting in the past so everytime you open iTunes after making that setting, only your downloaded songs will show.  No longer the case and very annoying.  I wish I could just delete those purchases from the past I will never listen to again.

Answer (score 2):

Okay. This is super annoying... but I think I figured it out. If you pull up the original list of songs in your music and scroll by song, the cloud songs will show up with a cloud next to them. Click and hold each individual song and then click delete from library. Again, super annoying, but even after syncing my phone again on my computer those songs stayed deleted. Hope this helps!

Comment: You can do this from the 'Albums' list - which makes it a bit quicker, & slightly less annoying.  :-/

Answer (score 1):

This feature does not exist on iOS10.

With iOS9 you could toggle "Only Downloaded Music" option from within the music app, which hid any purchases in the cloud (i.e. songs not actually downloaded to your device) from your device library.

As an alternative they have a Downloaded Music category in the Music app.
However really the Downloaded Music category is not a sufficient option, nor is hiding all the purchases from our iTunes account (as this would make them unavailable on other devices if wanted).

The best suggestion I could make is provide feedback to Apple http://www.apple.com/feedback/ in the hopes that they restore such an option in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

With my iPhone plugged into my laptop and after authorizing it via iTunes so that I had access to my purchases, I went to 'Account'and scrolled down to 'Purchased' after clicking it, all of my purchased music popped up. I clicked the first purchased song and scrolled down while holding shift before clicking the last purchased song so that all 300 and something songs were highlighted and right clicked/delete. Immediately, all of my years old purchased music was removed from the library on my phone.

Comment: OP doesn't have access to a computer

Comment: Does this remove them from your Apple account permanently as well?